# scipy.sparse.hstack [ValueError: blocks must be 2-D]

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

`a` and `b` is a 2nd numpy array, and I want to vertical stack and compress to sparse array.

I just use:

```py
c = sp.hstack([a, b])
```

but it throw the error:

```py
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    462 
    463     """
--> 464     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    465 
    466 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    545 
    546     if blocks.ndim != 2:
--> 547         raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
    548 
    549     M,N = blocks.shape

ValueError: blocks must be 2-D
```

but I remenber this code is works at my previous code.

Comment: The docs say: `sequence of sparse matrices with compatible shapes`.  It's not reliable with `ndarrays`.  I suspect your `a` and `b` have the same shape.  `blocks` in this error message refers to an array produced by `np.array([[a,b]], object)`.

Comment: `sparse.hstack` via `sparse.bmat` creates a `coo_matrix` from each input (a trivial task if they are already are sparse), and combines their attributes to makes a new `coo_matrix`.  If you are starting with numpy arrays, it would be faster to first combine them with `np.hstack` (or variants) and make the sparse matrix from that.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is in stack list at least contain a sparse array.

in other words, the code

```py
c = sp.hstack([a, b, c, d, ...])
```

in `[a, b, c, d, ...]` must at least contain a sparse array.

if the list not contain a sparse array, you can try:

```py
c = sp.hstack([sp.csr_matrix(a), b, c, d, ...])
```

and it works!

Comment: Actually the test is on the `ndim` of `np.array([[a,b]], object)`.  If `a` and `b` are sparse as specified in the docs, this works fine.  But `ndarray` with matching shapes can produce an array with higher dimensions.